# Buffer Overrun in OpenCV 2.4.9 FileStorage

Tags: c++, opencv, buffer-overrun

I recently upgraded to `OpenCV 2.4.9` and encountered a `Buffer Overrun` when executing this small piece of code when compiling in release mode:

```
std::string calibSettingFilename( "config.xml" );
cv::FileStorage fs( calibSettingFilename, FileStorage::READ );
```

Everything works fine in debug mode, so I am completely lost at where to look for the solution. If that helps, my callstack looks like this:

```
msvcr110.dll!_crt_debugger_hook(int _Reserved) Line 60  C
CameraCalibration.exe!__raise_securityfailure(_EXCEPTION_POINTERS * ExceptionPointers) Line 70  C
CameraCalibration.exe!__report_gsfailure() Line 235 C
CameraCalibration.exe!_memcpy()    C++
ntdll.dll!ExecuteHandler@20()  Unknown
ntdll.dll!_RtlDispatchException@8()    Unknown
ntdll.dll!_KiUserExceptionDispatcher@8()   Unknown
opencv_core249d.dll!cvOpenFileStorage(const char * filename, CvMemStorage * dststorage, int flags, const char * encoding) Line 2694 C++
opencv_core249d.dll!cv::FileStorage::open(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > & filename, int flags, const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > & encoding) Line 5177    C++
opencv_core249d.dll!cv::FileStorage::FileStorage(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > & filename, int flags, const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > & encoding) Line 5156 C++
CameraCalibration.exe!ReadCalibrationSettings(CalibrationSettings * * settings) Line 28 C++
```